# Matlab: Reduce second order matrix differential equation to standard eigenproblem

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to obtain the natural frequencies of a simple mechanical system with mass matrix M and stiffness matrix K (.mat-file -> [Download](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=B8636C4E5713FD05!878&authkey=!AC2f_3XAqvLyvaU&ithint=file%2Cmat)):

M*x''(t)+K*x(t)=0 (x= Position).

It means basically, that I have to solve det(K-w^2*M)=0. But how can I solve it in Matlab (or if necessary reduce it to a standard eigenvalue problem and solve it then)? The matrices are definitely solvable with Abaqus (FEM Software), but I have to solve it in Matlab.

I tried the following without success: det(K-w^2*M)=0 => det(M^-1*K-w^2*I)=0 (I := unity matrix) 
But solving this eigenvalue problem with

```
sqrt(eigs(K*M^-1))
```

delivers wrong values and the warning:

> "Matrix is singular to working precision.
>
> In matlab.internal.math.mpower.viaMtimes (line 35)"

Other wrong values can be obtained via det(K-w^2*M)=0 => det(I/(w^2)-M*K^-1)=0:

```
1./sqrt(eigs(M*K^-1))
```

Any hint would help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your problem is called [generalized eigenvalue problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Generalized_eigenvalue_problem) and "in most situations it is preferable not to perform the inversion, but rather to solve the generalized eigenvalue problem as stated originally". Fortunately, Matlab can handle this kind of problem. In your case: `eigs(K,M)`. The issue seems to be that both `M` and `K` are singular.

Comment: Thank you very much. The thing is just that the matrices are exactly the same as Abaqus solves. And Abaqus produces good results (,it can be verified analytically). Allow me a second question: Is it also possible to do it somehow with damping and complex eigen values in Matlab?

Comment: Yes, it is interesting that Abaqus can solve the problem. I am pretty sure that Matlab can handle complex eigenvalues, probably with damping too (proportional to velocity?). Regarding the original problem: it is quite strange that the stiffness matrix is singular, as it means that the structure cannot withstand any forces. Are you sure that these are the correct matrices? If yes, I would recommend to replicate Abaqus results first with a simple static problem where only the stiffness matrix is involved.

Comment: Thanks. Abaqus has an option to export the equation systems. I used it. I modelled a mass-less spring with small elasticity which is connected to a mass with a very high elasticity - so basically a mass-damper. But your hints gave me some ideas what I can do tomorrow. To the second question: Yes it is proportional to velocity- so very simple: Mx''(t)+Dx'(t)+Kx(t)=0

Answer (score 1):

As @Arpi mentioned, you actually want to solve the generalized eigenvalue problem:

K*x = w^2*M*x

Since your matrices K and M are apparently singular (or just one of them), it is not possible to use `eigs`, but you have to use `eig`:

```
V = eig(K,M);

w = sqrt(V);
```

Comment: `M` and `K` are sparse matrices, thus `eig` cannot be used.
"EIG does not support generalized eigenproblem EIG(A,B) when A or B is sparse. Use EIGS instead."

Comment: @Arpi And I guess the sparsity of K and M is important, since it is an FEM application. Then the singularity of the matrices (definitely K) must be solved first before `eigs` can be used. Is suspect some issues with the boundary conditions.